# Skip worksheet based on a value in cell A2 if blank/empty

Tags: excel, vba

I want to loop through specific sheets (codeNamed) and if there is a value is in cell A2 (not empty), I would want to perform some data copy to another sheet. I used the Select Case but it doesn't exit out when A2 is empty/blank, and go to the next Case.

'------------code---------

```
Sub Check()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case ws.CodeName
            Case Is = "shSelinsingImportLast"
                If Not IsEmpty(Range("A2")) Or Not Range("A2").Value = "" Then
                    'Do the copy data
                End If
        Case Is = "shSelinsingImportThis"
            If Not IsEmpty(Range("A2")) Or Not Range("A2").Value = "" Then
                'Do the copy data
            End If
        End Select
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It's important to remember that excel doesn't see empty and blank as the same thing. So it's possible a cell could be "" but not be empty, or vice versa. Either case would trigger your if statement

Try changing it to an AND statement instead of an OR

`If Not IsEmpty(Range("A2")) And Not Range("A2").Value = "" Then`

A detailed article on excel's behaviour in this [can be found here](https://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2014/10/31/is-your-cell-blank-or-empty/)

Comment: I changed to AND instead of OR but it still doesn't trigger the "IF" statement...also followed your link and copied the ISBLANK() function used that instead but it doesn't work either....the one sheet has A2 blank equals true but the code doesn't hop out to the next Case Is sheet with data....maybe what's the best way to exit select for one particular Case statement and move to the next Case when blank in A2 cell.

Answer (score 0):

### Empty vs Blank

- To consider blank cells which include empty cells and cells evaluating to "", "'", or whatnot, you can rather test the length of their contents e.g.:

  ```
  If Len(Cell.Value) > 0 Then
      ' Do something
  End If
  ```
- Note the worksheet reference (`ws`) in `ws.Range("A2").Value`. Your solution was looking in the active sheet.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Check()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case ws.CodeName
            Case "shSelinsingImportLast"
                If Len(ws.Range("A2").Value) > 0 Then
                    'Do the copy data
                End If
            Case "Whatever"
                If Len(ws.Range("A2").Value) > 0 Then
                    'Do the copy data
                End If
            Case Else
        End Select
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: VBasic2008....Your suggestion did the magic!...You're abolutely brilliant...thanks you so much....it was agonising me for the last couple of days and now it's resolved.